# Отсортировать однонаправленный список

Tags: c

подскажите пожалуйста как мне отсортировать однонаправленный список по переменной kol в порядке уменьшения данной переменной

```
struct prog {
char name[80];
unsigned int kol;
double time1;
double time2;

struct prog* next;
};
```

Comment: Что значит "подскажите"? Что Вы уже умеете? Умеете отсортировать массив? Умеете сравнить два элемента списка? Умеете поменять местами два элемента в односвязном списке?

Comment: Igor, не могу придумать как мне сделать условие для сортировки и как поменять местами два элемента в односвязном списке

Comment: В таком случае надо задавать вопрос: "Я написал код, который должен менять местами два элемента в односвязном списке. Когда я его запускаю вот с такими данными - ..., происходит вот это - ..., а должно - вот это ... Где у меня ошибка?"

Comment: И еще. Зачем Вы все время удаляете предыдущую учетную запись и заводите новую?